# Encrypt server port in springboot application properties using jasypt

Tags: spring-boot, jasypt

I am using jasypt to encrypt some properties in application.properties file of my springboot application.
I have a requirement to encrypt the server port as well.

When I encrypt it and run my application the application does not start.

I get the below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'ENC(OWRKKTBHQcjWItQG/+V7hw==)'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ENC(OWRKKTBHQcjWItQG/+V7hw==)"
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
```

looks like its not decrypting the property

below is my jasypt custom configuration

```
@Configuration
public class JasyptEncryptionConfig {
public final static String ENCRYPTION_KEY = "Ph03nix5parr0w!m@ven!r";

@Bean(name ="jasyptStringEncryptor")
public StringEncryptor passwordEncryptor(){
    PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
    SimpleStringPBEConfig config = new SimpleStringPBEConfig();
    config.setPassword(ENCRYPTION_KEY); // encryptor's private key
    config.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    config.setKeyObtentionIterations("1000");
    config.setPoolSize("1");
    config.setProviderName("SunJCE");
    config.setSaltGeneratorClassName("org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator");
    config.setStringOutputType("base64");
    encryptor.setConfig(config);
    return encryptor;
}

}
```

below are the application properties

```
server.port: ENC(OWRKKTBHQcjWItQG/+V7hw==)
management.port: ENC(OWRKKTBHQcjWItQG/+V7hw==)
management.address: 127.0.0.1
management.context-path: /actuator
```

Other properties are working fine, only server port does not work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Maybe you can use environment as screen.

You cannot change port int to String config.setStringOutputType("base64");

```
ServerProperties.class public void setPort(Integer port)
```

Comment: Should I create another property called SERVER_PORT in application. properties which point to the encrypted value? e.g SERVER_PORT:ENC(OWRKKTBHQcjWItQG/+V7hw==) and point my server.port to ${SERVER_PORT}.

Comment: Maybe you exclude ServerProperties. And write own ServerProperties